# /etc/hosts file manipulation programmatically in android

Tags: java, android, root

Though I've write some small applications with android before, now I trying to write a root application and having some problems regarding file permissions.

Basically, my aim is to manipulate /etc/hosts file with a Java application. As my first action, I've gained root privileges with runtime.exec("su") and tried to open hosts file with standard ways like using File() or FileOutputStream(). But unsuccessfully, my application threw the following exception "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/hosts (Permission denied)". Then I checked the permissions for file via accessing shell, and it was like rw-r--r-- for root. Even if it supposed to work with this permissions, I changed it to 777 from shell and voila! my application started to open file without any problem. 
However, since android replaces the hosts file with default version time to time, it also changes the permission for the file and with previous method, each time I have to go and change permission from adb and surely this is not I want. So, step by step;

-I tried runtime.exec("chmod 777 /etc/hosts") method and this didn't work without any exception or error message.

-Then I tried to use File.setWritable() method but it doesn't exist in my andoid system, though it seems supposed to be android 2.2 according to javadoc.

-Lastly, I tried to set working directory with System.setProperty("user.dir","/etc/") and use openFileOutput("hosts", MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE) but of course this didn't work, either.
Now, I'm all out of any ideas right now. What is the way to manipulate system files in android?
regards,

Comment: You're modifying things you shouldn't have to modify. Android makes this difficult because it's precisely the type of thing malicious software may try to do should it ever gain privileged access to the underlying operating system. Perhaps you can share more of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: better than my response, which was going to be "aaarrrrgggghhhhh, don't do that!"

Comment: i can't think of a non-malicious reason for doing that.

Comment: I can think of plenty of non-malicious reasons, for example blocking a malicious (or at least highly annoying) site which many others try to include content from.  But Android isn't well suited to customizations.

Comment: as Chris said, there may be plenty of reasons to do sth like this on a smartphone but let me clarify my aim; unfortunately my country has a ridiculous internet access policy which sometimes can be named as censorship for many cases. Since, sometime some of the ip blocks for big sites are banned without declaring any reason or by mistake(!),it is a daily thing for even non power users to change hosts file with static declaration of ip-host matching.So just unlikely with your comments, trying to do non-allowed thing can be done not for doing bad things but for achieving freedom sometimes;)

Comment: China? Lovely country but a pain to search the web!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've gained root privileges with runtime.exec("su")

Not for your java code you haven't.  What su does is let you launch a stand alone native executable as root.  It *does not* change the uid of an existing process, such as the dalvik vm running your code.

> Even if it supposed to work with this permissions, I changed it to 777 from shell and voila! my application started to open file without any problem.

Yes, you did the privileged task from a privileged process, and then your non-privileged java app could take care of the followup.

> However, since android replaces the hosts file with default version time to time, it also changes the permission for the file and with previous method, each time I have to go and change permission from adb and surely this is not I want.

This suggests that changing the hosts file yourself is a bad idea, as you could end up in a revert war with Android (though why Android would try changing a file located on a normally read-only file system is a bit mysterious)

> What is the way to manipulate system files in android? regards,

Short answer: you don't

Long answer: you take time understand how Android wants to use them, and you change this behavior of Android itself in a modified version.  (you might start with a grep of the sources for the file name)

Comment: Chris, actually this su trick I wrote above was found from a forum while searching for how to write root android app and since my phone mislead me with saying "I've gained superuser privileges" I blindly trusted it and thought I'm the god for phone now, but not it makes a lot more sense. Though, I still couldn't reach the end yet about my first aim -best practices for root application writing-, your way suggested will be a starting point for me regarding this hosts file issue. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must edit the hosts file (which is a bad idea, as stated in other answer(s)) you find it under /system/etc/hosts and do that via adb pull, editing the file on your computer, adb remount and adb push. Files in the / partition are mounted with a NAND lock, that would have to be lifted by a custom rom, which means that your app would then  probably only work with one special rom that does that.